# Angular: window.print() unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I need help to write a unit test of my method but I don't know how to do it.
So if anyone can give me a hand, you will save my day.

my method:

```
print(component) {
  window.print();
  window.cancel();
}
```

how can I test this method?

Comment: What do you want to test ? It does not make sense to test that `window.print` actually prints (because it means unit testing the browser). You can maybe mock `window` in order to unit test that the method is called instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
it('should call print and cancel', () => {
  // spy on print and cancel on window object
  const printSpy = spyOn(window, 'print');
  const cancelSpy = spyOn(window, 'cancel');

  // call print
  component.print({/* mock component however you wish here */});

  // expect print and cancel spy to have been called
  expect(printSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(cancelSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If you're new to unit testing, this is a great resource: https://testing-angular.com/.

Comment: I wonder if you are missing something after the first spyOn, something like `.and.callthrough()` or `.and.return(null)` or the code will hang after `window.print`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You could do that but I don't think it will hang. I think when you `spyOn` a method, it will return `undefined` when it is actually called which is Ok in this case.

Comment: thank you!  it works!
i'll start reading  right now